# Twilio: Add/Change Phonenumber programmatically

Tags: javascript, php, twilio

How can I add/edit phonenumber programmatically using the API in https://www.twilio.com/user/account/voice/phone-numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To provision a new phone number using the Twilio API is a two step process. First, you need to find an available phone number using the [Available Phone Numbers resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers). You can do this in PHP like so:

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "{{ account_sid }}"; 
$token = "{{ auth_token }}"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$numbers = $client->account->available_phone_numbers->getList('US', 'Local');
foreach($numbers->available_phone_numbers as $number) {
    echo $number->phone_number;
}
```

Second, you need to make a [request to the Incoming Phone Numbers resource to purchase that number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#list-post).

```
// choose $twilio_number from the previous response.
$number = $client->account->incoming_phone_numbers->create(array(
    "FriendlyName" => "My Company Line",
    "VoiceUrl" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
    "PhoneNumber" => $twilio_number
));
```

You can then update the number using the [Incoming Phone Numbers instance resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#instance-post).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks philnash =)